# Cannot access asp.net changepassword controls in codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-controls, change-password

I cannot access any of my asp controls in my codebehind. The .aspx page is as follows

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ChangePassword.aspx.cs" Inherits="ChangePassword" ValidateRequest="false"  %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<asp:ChangePassword ID="ChangePassword1" runat="server" CssClass="MinutesList" 
    onchangedpassword="ChangePassword1_ChangedPassword">
    <ChangePasswordTemplate>
        <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                Change Your Password</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                <asp:Label ID="CurrentPasswordLabel" runat="server" 
                                    AssociatedControlID="CurrentPassword">Password:</asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="CurrentPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Visible="false" >></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="CurrentPasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                                    ControlToValidate="CurrentPassword" ErrorMessage="Password is required." 
                                    ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="ChangePassword1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                <asp:Label ID="NewPasswordLabel" runat="server" 
                                    AssociatedControlID="NewPassword">New Password:</asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="NewPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="NewPasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                                    ControlToValidate="NewPassword" ErrorMessage="New Password is required." 
                                    ToolTip="New Password is required." ValidationGroup="ChangePassword1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                <asp:Label ID="ConfirmNewPasswordLabel" runat="server" 
                                    AssociatedControlID="ConfirmNewPassword">Confirm New Password:</asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmNewPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ConfirmNewPasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                                    ControlToValidate="ConfirmNewPassword" 
                                    ErrorMessage="Confirm New Password is required." 
                                    ToolTip="Confirm New Password is required." ValidationGroup="ChangePassword1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                <asp:CompareValidator ID="NewPasswordCompare" runat="server" 
                                    ControlToCompare="NewPassword" ControlToValidate="ConfirmNewPassword" 
                                    Display="Dynamic" 
                                    ErrorMessage="The Confirm New Password must match the New Password entry." 
                                    ValidationGroup="ChangePassword1"></asp:CompareValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color:Red;">
                                <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                <asp:Button ID="ChangePasswordPushButton" runat="server" 
                                    CommandName="ChangePassword" Text="Change Password" 
                                    ValidationGroup="ChangePassword1" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="CancelPushButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                    CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ChangePasswordTemplate>
    <SuccessTemplate>
        <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                Change Password Complete</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Your password has been changed!</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="HomePageButton" runat="server" Text="Continue" CausesValidation="true" 
                                    onclick="HomePageButton_Click" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </SuccessTemplate>
</asp:ChangePassword>
</asp:Content>
```

The codebehind is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class ChangePassword : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //TextBox password = (TextBox)ChangePassword1.FindControl("CurrentPassword");
    //Label passwordLabel = (Label)ChangePassword1.FindControl("CurrentPasswordLabel");
    TextBox password = ChangePassword1.FindControl("CurrentPassword") as TextBox;
    Label passwordLabel = ChangePassword1.FindControl("CurrentPasswordLabel") as Label;
    //TextBox CurrentPassword = ChangePassword1.FindControl("CurrentPassword") as TextBox;
    if (Request.QueryString["p"] != null)
    {
        passwordLabel.Visible = false;
        password.TextMode = TextBoxMode.SingleLine;
        password.Visible = false;
        password.Text = Request.QueryString["p"];
    }
}
protected void ChangePassword1_ChangedPassword(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void HomePageButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Link.ToHomePage();
    Response.Redirect("HomePage.aspx");
}

}
```

The problem I am having is I get a object reference not set to an instance of an object on passwordLabel and password. Does anyone know how to get these into scope so that I can edit there text and visibility properties in the codebehind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using:

```
  TextBox password = ChangePassword1.Controls[0].FindControl("CurrentPassword") as TextBox;
  Label passwordLabel = ChangePassword1.Controls[0].FindControl("CurrentPasswordLabel") as Label;
```

Comment: Thanks @Adil Mammadov, it worked perfectly. Can you explain why this worked and the other ways did not?

Comment: I am glad that it worked. I think it is due to you have to templates in ChangePassword1 : ChangePasswordTemplate and SuccessTemplate. Because your TextBox and Label are in the first template you have to write Controls[0]. If they were in SuccessTempate it would be Controls[1]. May be I am mistaken, please try getting "HomePageButton" in SuccessTemplate and write Controls[1]. If it works that means I am not mistaken :)

Answer (score 1):

Using ChangePasswordTemplateContainer instead of the Controls[0] won't be subject to changing the order of the templates in the control. For instance... adding a SuccessTemplate before the ChangePasswordTemplate will cause the Controls[0] code to break.

> ChangePassword1.ChangePasswordTemplateContainer.FindControl("CurrentPassword")